# list all the names inside an object that are bound to a specific type

Tags: python

How can I list all of the names inside an object that are bound to a specific type?

For example, if an object has several attributes, how can I list only integer attributes of that object?

Comment: Well, how do you cycle through all of the attributes of an object?  How do you check the type of something?  These are both well-documented and easy enough to search, so I'm unsure of where you're stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for v in YourObject.__dict__.values():
    if type(v) == int:
        print v
```

`__dict__` attribute of objects returns a `dict` of all the variables and their names in the object. Simply test each one of the variables using the `type()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please help me do the same, with the __dir__() method?